# Updating custom DLL to a newer version

Tags: dll, reporting-services

I am using a custom dll with SSRS. After deployment, I may need to update my custom dll with a newer version. Will my reports continue to work?

If the reports do not work with the new version of the dll, how can I get my reports to work with the newer version of the dll?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work, but can't you run a small test to varefy that ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **yes**, at least in my experience. I've done this successfully in the past - just replace the relevant custom DLL on the server with the updated version. I didn't have to make any changes to the reports using the DLL.

One caveat here - when I was replacing a DLL in situ I would make sure the version number of the DLL was the same; since the report stores the DLL version number this meant as far as the reports were concerned they were still getting the same DLL.

So if you're incrementing version numbers when building your DLL this *might* not work. As per the comment from *@Gil Peretz* just test it out in a non-production environment and see what happens.